# Windows file creation date/time using python

Tags: python, datetime

I need to get a file creation date&time using python. I tried:

```
os.stat(r"path")[ST_CTIME]
```

But it is returning:

```
1263538277
```

This is not the creation date time. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: By the way, since Python 2.2 you can access the items in the return value more easily as attributes, thus `os.stat(r'path').st_ctime`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not?

```
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(1263538277)
'Fri Jan 15 04:51:17 2010'
```

Looks like a valid creation time to me.

Comment: +1 Short and elegant, if you're interested in the textual representation.

Answer (score 5):

From [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/520807-st_ctime-convert-yyyymmdd):

```
import os
import time
create_date = os.stat('/tmp/myfile.txt')[9]
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.gmtime(create_date))
```

Which gives:

```
2009-11-25
```

You can also try:

```
print time.gmtime(create_date)
(2009, 11, 25, 13, 37, 9, 2, 329, 0)
```

For a more accurate timestamp.

Note that the time returned by `time.gmtime()` returns GMT; See [the `time` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) for other functions, like `localtime()`.

Comment: Perhaps `os.stat('/tmp/myfile.txt').st_ctime` would be better than `os.stat('/tmp/myfile.txt')[9]`, as long as python ≥2.2

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it isn't? Using [unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) it converts to "01/18/2010 @ 7:34am" which at least makes sense.

The timestamp is returned as a time in seconds from 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat

> st_ctime (platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows)

Everything is OK.

Comment: I think he needs the conversion between the integer and a more readable time format.