# Is there a way to get the year a file was created with python?

Tags: python

The title says it all. I am trying to get the year a file was created for indexing purposes. Also, I'm on windows if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest there are similar questions e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960477/how-to-read-file-attributes-in-directory)

`os.stat` is your friend. It provides various stats on a file. Use `ctime` to change it into something human readable as demo'd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085992/windows-file-creation-date-time-using-python)

```
import os.path, time
when = os.stat(r"path").st_ctime
time.ctime(when)
```

Answer (score 1):

this question has been already asked, short story here, see the code below:

```
import os.path, time
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
```

and here is link:
[How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: No, it is not the proper solution, as getctime is returning the last Change time. and not Creation time

Answer (score 0):

so here's the solution:

```
import os
import datetime

#gives the create time as a unix timestamp
create_time = os.stat(<path to file>).st_ctime

#returns a datetime object
create_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time)

#print the year
create_datetime.strftime("%Y")
```

Comment: No, it is not the proper solution, as st_ctime is returning the last Change time. and not Creation time

Comment: @RuchirShukla that's what the documentation defines it does, on unix systems - https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.ST_CTIME

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying."On some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time (see platform documentation for details)."