# Get creation date of a file, calculate with it and show result

Tags: windows

I have a very specific task to do:

I have 200 files and need to have the creation in relation to each other.

- First file created:     22:20 AM
- Seconde file created:   22:32 AM
- Third file created:     22:33 AM

The output should look about like this:

- 1: 00:00 hours:minutes
- 2: 00:12 hours:minutes
- 3: 00:13 hours:minutes

So how much time after the first file where the others created.
How can I do this within windows? The language doesn't matter and output only need to be readable by a human

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows file creation date/time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085992/windows-file-creation-date-time-using-python)

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14926/setting-timecode-in-premiere-pro-by-using-file-creation-date-of-clips This might help

Comment: @ShakedEyal I would not say it is a duplicate, as "your" question only asks how to get creation date with python. And I ask for what works best and how to calculate with it